# Как получить значение переменной из javascript в php?

Tags: php, javascript

Пишу сайт на php. Написан небольшой рабочий парсер новостных статей с некого новостного ресурса. Однако, парсер рабочий до того момента, пока не появилась необходимость применить javascript.

По задумке, парсер должен работать следующим образом:

1. В файле news_highlights.php имеется код, который парсит заголовки статей и выводит их у меня на главной странице.
2. Имеется файл script.js с кодом javascript, который по клику на определенный спарсенный заголовок изымает ссылку на полный текст выбранной статьи в источнике и помещает эту ссылку в сессию javascript с помощью команды sessionStorage.setItem.
3. Имеется файл page-news-article.php, содержащий код, который уже, собственно, парсит всю статью, используя ссылку, полученную в пункте 2.

Содержимое файлов - ниже.

Вопрос: почему в php файле № 3 я могу получить значение переменной js (ссылку на статью источника) и вывести его через echo на странице, но при этом скрипт php, находящийся в том же файле № 3, на отрез отказывается принимать его? Как мне заставить php принять переменную (ссылку на статью источника) и выполнить скрипт?

Сразу отмечу, Ajax мне не подходит, мне нужно, чтобы статья открывалась на другой странице. Хотя с Ajax всё работает как часы от начала до конца :)

В браузере получаю следующее:

http://some-site.com/information/prime-anonce-38.html

> Warning: file_get_contents( var data =
>   sessionStorage.getItem('setUrl'); document.write(data); )
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument
>   in Z:\home\my-site\www\wp-content\themes\WP_CLEAN\simple_html_dom.php
>   on line 76
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   Z:\home\my-site\www\wp-content\themes\WP_CLEAN\page-news-article.php
>   on line 14

1. news_highlights.php

```html
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
   
  $html = file_get_html(some-site.com);
  $a = 1; $b = 1; $c = 1;
   foreach($html->find('div.post-feed article a, article picture.icon-wrapper img, div.post-feed article h3, div.post-feed article p') as $highlights) {
    if ($highlights->tag == 'a'):
     echo '<div id="news-highlight-'.$a++.'" class="news-highlights"><a id="href-to-source-article-'.$b++.'" class="href-to-source-article" href="http://some-site.com'.$highlights->href.'"><a id="article-'.$c++.'" class="article" href="http://my-site/article/"><article>';
    elseif ($highlights->tag == 'img'):
     echo '<img src="http://some-site.com'.$highlights->src.'" alt="'.$highlights->alt.'">';
    elseif ($highlights->tag == 'h3'):
     echo $highlights;
    elseif ($highlights->tag == 'p'):
     echo $highlights . '</article></a></a></div>'."\n";
    endif;
   } 
 }
?>
```

2. script.js

```js
$(document).on('click','.news-highlights', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var id1 = $('.href-to-source-article', this).attr('id');
 var valUrl = $('#' + id1).attr('href');
  sessionStorage.setItem('setUrl', valUrl);
  var data = sessionStorage.getItem('setUrl');
  alert(data);
  document.location.href = 'http://agama/wp-content/themes/WP_CLEAN/page-news-article.php';
 
  return false;
});
```

3. page-news-article.php

```html
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$q = "<script> var data = sessionStorage.getItem('setUrl'); document.write(data); </script>";
echo $q;
         
  $html = file_get_html($q);
  $a = 1; $b = 1; $c = 1;
   foreach($html->find('div.article-area div.column-non-right article h1, div.article-area div.column-non-right article div.article-text p, div.article-area div.column-non-right article div.article-text img') as $highlights) {
    if ($highlights->tag == 'h1'):
     echo $highlights;
    elseif ($highlights->tag == 'p'):
     echo $highlights;
    elseif ($highlights->tag == 'img'):
     echo '<img src="'.$highlights->src.'" alt="'.$highlights->alt.'">';
    endif;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Тот момент когда не знаешь, отредактировать заголовок вопроса, или подождать когда это сделает кто-нибудь более занудный, или какой-нибудь кармофермер

Comment: Тот момент, когда смотришь в код и просто офигеваешь )))

Comment: Тот момент, когда пишешь комментарий просто чтобы продолжить в тему.

Comment: Тот момент, когда вы зануды)) Лучше совет дельный по моему вопросу дайте :) Уже вторую неделю мучаюсь, еще и не такое извращение в коде за это время побывало в поисках решения)))

Comment: Тот момент, когда пришёл и переименовал вопрос, обломав малину занудам, кармофермерам и комментаторам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотя бы понимаете что делает код:

```
$q = "<script> var data = sessionStorage.getItem('setUrl'); document.write(data); </script>";
echo $q;
```

Что содержит переменная $q? Если вы думаете, что в ней лежит URL, то у меня плохие новости )))
На стороне JS пишите в куки, а не в sessionStorage. И на стороне php читайте как положено из массива $_COOKIE.

Comment: Я не программист по образованию, хотя мне это нравится и всё, что в этих кодах написано - написано мной, пусть даже коряво))) но что делает этот код - понимаю. Другой вопрос - почему он через echo выводит именно ссылку, а в скрипте php нет?

Куки попробую, но какие минусы/плюсы использования печенек? Принцип как в Get - через ссылку?

Comment: Да, кстати, в js файле много мусора типа алерт и т.д. - это для экспериментов делал и всё почиститься в итоге, когда найду ответ на вопрос, так что не надо сильно бить ногами за плохой код))

Comment: А вы вместо "echo $q;" напишите "var_dump($q);" и увидите разницу. И все таки используйте куки или передавайте URL через GET параметр.

Comment: Как быть?

Использовал куки - принимает переменную, а не её значение (не ссылку).

script.js

$(document).on('click','.news-highlights', function(){
 var id = $('.href-to-source-article', this).attr('id');
 var valUrl = $('#' + id).attr('href');
  document.cookie = "setUrl=valUrl";
  document.location.href = 'http://my-site/wp-content/themes/WP_CLEAN/page-news-article.php';
  return false;
});

В php принимаю так и пытаюсь вывести, чтоб проверить: $q = $_COOKIE['setUrl'];
echo $q;