# Вставить в php код переменную из javascript или избежать перезаписи переменной в цикле

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

есть код спиннера в котором накликивается значение, которое сохраняется в js переменную и ссылка формируемая через php.

```
    <script>function qty() {return document.getElementById('qty').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');                                                }</script><div class="mv-spinner-style-2">                                               <input id="qty" type="text" name="test138" value="1" onclick="qty()"                                                       class="qwe"/></div>
<button type="button"onclick="window.location.href='<?= Url::toRoute(['/controller/action','id'=>$model->id,'q'=>$тут_переменная])?>'"
class="qwe"></button>
```

нужно как-то обновлять генерируемый урл. (а именно qty)...

изначально проблема была в том,что у меня сейчас цикл и в нем есть переменная,эта переменная каждый раз перезапысывается, и соотв при нажатии на кнопку вставляется айдишник последнего значения. Потому я начал через пхп формировать запрос. Может можно избежать перезаписывания переменной отвечающей за айди и создавать по одной каждую итерацию цикла? 
вот код:

```
<?php foreach ($q as $model): ?>
    <script>
        function qty() {
            return document.getElementById('qty').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var mid = "<?php echo $model->id ?>";
    </script>
    <button type="button"
            onclick="window.location.href='/cart/create?id='+mid+'&q='+qty()"
            class="mv-btn mv-btn-style-3 btn-1-h-50 responsive-btn-1-type-3 btn-add-to-cart">
            <span class="btn-inner">
                <i class="btn-icon fa fa-cart-plus"></i>
                <span class="btn-text"></span>
            </span>
    </button>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: "Вставить в php код переменную из javascript" - так не получится, php скрипт уже закончил работу. Можно сделать ajax запрос и вызвать скрипт php с указанными параметрами, в том числе со значением переменной js.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить значение переменной из javascript в php?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561941/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-javascript-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: модифицировал вопрос,дабы понятнее было суть проблемы

Comment: вставить в html переменную mid которая в js хранится может как-то..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо за помощь **vp_arth**.
нужно развесить на спиннеры айдишники, и модернизировать функцию получения количества qty() добавив в нее айдишник товара, дабы она отдавала количество с нужного спиннера в гриде в ссылкув кнопку.
Решение выглядит по итогу так:

```
    <?php foreach($models as $model):?>
     <div class="mv-spinner-style-2">
<input onclick="qty(<?=$model->id?>)" id="qty_<?=$model->id?>" type="text" name="test138" value="1"
class="mv-inputbox mv-only-numeric input-quantity-cart"/>
</div>

<script>
function qty(model_id) {
return document.getElementById('qty_'+model_id).getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
}
</script>
     <button type="button"                                                    onclick="window.location.href='/cart/create?id='+<?=$model->id?>+'&q='+qty(<?=$model->id?>)"
class="mv-btn mv-btn-style-3 btn-1-h-50 responsive-btn-1-type-3 btn-add-to-cart">
<span class="btn-inner"><i
class="btn-icon fa fa-cart-plus"></i><span
class="btn-text"></span></span>
</button>
    <?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Генерация блоков js в цикле php - почти всегда плохая идея...

```
<?php 
// Все необходимые данные собираем вне шаблона, чтобы не засорять его лишней логикой
$model_ids = [];
foreach ($q as $model) {
    $model_ids[] = $model->id;
}
?>

<script>
function qty() {
    return document.getElementById('qty').getAttribute('aria-valuenow');
}

// с помощью этого можно динамически сгенерировать все кнопки в javascript
// var model_ids = <?=json_encode($model_ids)?>;

</script>

<?php foreach ($model_ids as $id):?>
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/cart/create?id='+<?=$id?>+'&q='+qty()"
    class="mv-btn mv-btn-style-3 btn-1-h-50 responsive-btn-1-type-3 btn-add-to-cart">
    <span class="btn-inner">
        <i class="btn-icon fa fa-cart-plus"></i>
        <span class="btn-text"></span>
    </span>
</button>
<?endforeach?>
```

Comment: используя ваш код, корректно добавляется первый айтем из списка, а начиная со второго - по одному летят в корзину. т.е qty не передается а айдишник - да

Comment: Вы считаете, в вашем вопросе достаточно данных, чтобы понять что не так? В параметр q передаётся текущее значение атрибута aria-valuenow элемента с id=qty. Как там у вас должно быть - я не знаю. Быть может, у вас несколько элементов с id=qty?

Comment: я пытаюсь выдать как можно больше инфы чтобы было понятней суть проблемы.
у меня цикл, получающий AR товаров ($model). Этот цикл строит строки таблицы. В одной строке есть спиннер, которым накликивается (или вводится) количество, рядом кнопка button на которой висит ссылка на контроллер с 2мя параметрами. 1 параметр - айди товара (понятное дело в цикле он $model->id будет менятся постоянно) и количество которое получили из спиннера посредством qty().

Comment: все ваши спиннеры с одинаковым id? На странице не должно быть неуникальных id. В данный момент на все кнопки влияет самый первый спиннер.

Comment: кажется я начинаю понимать в чем дело. Присваиваю спиннеру айдишник (пускай это будет код товара)
 <input id="qty_.<?=$model->id?>." type="text" name="test138" value="1"
class="mv-inputbox mv-only-numeric input-quantity-cart"/>
и формирую батон:
 <button type="button"
onclick="window.location.href='/cart/create?id='+<?=$model->id?>+'&q='+qty()" class="mv-btn mv-btn-style-3 btn-1-h-50 responsive-btn-1-type-3 btn-add-to-cart">
<span class="btn-inner"><i
class="btn-icon fa fa-cart-plus"></i><span
class="btn-text"></span></span>
</button>
и ничего. что-т плавит уже от этого(

Comment: в функцию  qty теперь передайте айди, чтобы можно было получить правильный спиннер с помощью getElementById

Comment: спасибо что помогаете,но вот чувствую что в какой-то мелочи затуп =\
function qty() {return document.getElementById('qty_<?=$model->id?>').getAttribute('aria-valuenow'); }
<div class="mv-spinner-style-2"> <input  onclick="qty()" 
id="qty_<?=$model->id?>" type="text" name="test138" value="1" class="mv-inputbox mv-only-numeric input-quantity-cart"/>                                      </div>
сами дивы строятся с айдишниками как надо

Comment: Нет! `function qty(model_id){ return document.getElementById('qty_'+model_id).getAtt...` И `...&qty=qty(<?=$model->id?>)`

Comment: огромное спасибо, мог бы 5 плюсов поставить - поставил бы). помогло

Comment: добавил ответ. еще раз спасибо.